# SilkTest Identify/Locator Spy Window not seeing any objects in web browser window

Tags: silktest

SilkTest Locator spy is unable to recognize any of my web applications. It will see the main html page but no of the dom elements that lie Under it. It is weird because it used to work but im not sure if a setting change can cause this. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling silktest and I get the same problems.

Comment: Hi! Which version of Silk Test and which browsers (and which browser versions) are you using? Have any of those versions changed recently?

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Ralph, remember that Firefox and Chrome are on a 6 week release schedule which means that you could have an incompatible version of one of these browsers.  Check the Micro Focus Support site to see what version of Silk Test supports the versions of the browser that you are using.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding 'application configuration' for all apps to spy objects in silkTest with locator spy.

Locator spy identifies only those applications which are added in application configurations.